# Microphone makes a buzzing sound in laptop when I plug in the charger

Tags: laptop, audio, microphone, noise

I recently bought new headset and when I tested the microphone on my laptop it had a buzzing sound. I realised that it only does that noise when I plug in the charger of the laptop. Also, when it's plugged in, it stops when I touch the vga port or a usb port.

My headset is a Redragon Hylas H260 and my laptop is an Acer Aspire E1-471.
What can I do to fix the buzzing sound?

Comment: Sounds like a false ground path between headset and computer, poor connection, or poor ground connection.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your laptop power supply is not grounded, causing hum. Some power supplies have only a two prong connector, and some users connect a three-prong, grounded supply using an adapter *without connecting the ground tab*.

- If you're using a three-prong to two-prong adapter at the mains outlet, fasten the tab of the adapter to the cover-plate screw to safely ground it.
- If the power supply itself has only a two-prong plug, either buy a *grounded* supply with the same ratings, or use the circuit below to provide an AC ground, reducing hum.

[image: AC Ground for Laptop]

When my laptop had a similar issue, (and I could even *feel* a buzzing sensation when running a hand over metal parts!), I created that simple circuit to bypass AC to ground. Parts values are not critical; a larger resistor and/or capacitor would be acceptable. The capacitor should be rated for at least 300 VAC.

Connect one wire to an earth ground, e.g., screw holding on the cover plate of an outlet, or a metal water pipe. Connect the other to a wire that wraps around the metal barrel of the power supply DC plug (best), or to the chassis of the laptop (might not be electrically connected).

The capacitor shunts AC to ground, and the resistor prevents a static charge building up on the capacitor.

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this? I can't understand your diagram, here in my country we don't use earth ground and I can't plug something to a water pipe because they are in other rooms. I've heard of Ground Loops Isolators that use 3.5mm jack, maybe that will work?

Comment: You don't have 3-prong outlets in your country?

Comment: We use both 2 and 3 prong outlets but the 3rd prong is, as far as I know, usually never used. Sorry for a late response, I didn't think I'd get a reply.

Comment: Edit: 3rd prong is usually not grounded or wired to anything here.

Comment: That's rather scary -- one could plug in a *theoretically* grounded appliance, only to get electrocuted because of leakage to the chassis. You're sure the third line on an outlet is **not** grounded??